# Do we need [texas-instruments]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Do we really need the [texas-instruments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/texas-instruments) tag?

Its summary suggests nothing useful relating to Stack Overflow:

> Texas Instruments Inc. (TI) is an American company that designs and makes semiconductors, which it sells to electronics designers and manufacturers globally.

Most of its questions appear to be about [ti-basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ti-basic) or hardware, which is off-topic.

Examples:

1. [How to create TI-BASIC (TI-84+) input forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28734994/how-to-create-ti-basic-ti-84-input-forms) ([ti-basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ti-basic))
2. [How to connect to my LaunchPad TM4C123G](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661638/how-to-connect-to-my-launchpad-tm4c123g) (hardware)
3. [Creating a custom TI 84 plus graphing calculator Operating System (OS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152810/creating-a-custom-ti-84-plus-graphing-calculator-operating-system-os) ([calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/calculator))

Also, while we're at it, we probably can get rid of the [ti-83](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ti-83), [ti-84](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ti-84), and [ti-nspire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ti-nspire) tags, which are just calculator models, but there aren't too many questions in those, so that shouldn't be too much of a problem.

Comment: The TI-83 and 84 questions that are about programming the calculator should be moved to ti-basic.  I believe they use the same language.

Comment: @GabeSechan They do.

Comment: Are there no questions about programming apps for the TI-83/84 or whatever other raw-binary programming models TI provided that I have long forgotten by now?

Comment: Good point. Both flash and Ti-ASM can also be used to program the 83-84 models, so using just the tag "TI-basic" could be misleading

Comment: For the record, though, TI89 uses a different (similar but sooo much nicer) Basic variant. I remember back in high school (so ages ago), that was half the reason I was so excited to upgrade to an 89. (Namely, being able to name variables something other than single letters! Yes, really.)

Comment: However, the TI-Basic for nspire is very different than the one used on those 68k calculators. That tag should stand.

Comment: That was where the rot set in then.  What's wrong with single letters? - there are 26 of them, you know.  Now we get Java apps with enormouslyLongVariableNames that make you ugrade your screen so that you can read them :-(

Comment: I used to program a TI calculator; it would seem a useful tag to me; though I have nothing to do in that realm now!

Comment: @JosephDoggie Out of curiosity, why? Removing the tag doesn't prevent questions about TI calculator programming; it just rids SO of a useless categorization.

Comment: This discussion just brings me back to the old days ... removing the tag implies to me banning, but I guess it doesn't so in that case it's ok with me; not that anyone needs my permission anyway... anyone remember HP and RPN?  My dad saw a calculator ad that said it was "so advanced it had no equal" and at first I thought that was just a slogan, but it was true!

Answer (score 28):

Besides calculators, TI makes many [embedded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded) [microcontrollers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microcontrollers), and has it's own IDE/compiler toolchain: [code-composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-composer).

I think they have enough quirks from the standard gcc/x86 platform to merit their own category.  I monitor the TI tag for interesting questions about stuff I have worked with.

Code Composer already has its own tag. If [texas-instruments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/texas-instruments) is too generic, I'd like to at least see at [ti-microprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ti-microprocessor) tag to replace it where appropriate.  I have no opinion about ti-calculators.

Comment: We don't have a [tag:google] tag (and both the [tag:apple] and [tag:microsoft] tags have "DO NOT USE") for a reason; the manufacturer isn't that relevant, and if there are enough questions about a specific product, it should have its own tag. [tag:texas-instruments] is definitely too broad in my opinion (and it adds nothing to the question), so I'm all for retagging it to be more specific (as you suggested).

Comment: Probably worth noting that [tag:motorola], [tag:intel] and [tag:sony] do exist though, @AstroCB...

Comment: @Shog9 Interesting...

Answer (score 8):

I've burned the [ti-83](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ti-83), [ti-84](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ti-84), and [ti-nspire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ti-nspire) tags, as they added nothing to any of the questions that they adorned.

I cleaned up those questions, and most of them ended up being mildly on-topic after that, but I still think that [texas-instruments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/texas-instruments) is pretty useless (it has 108 questions, so I'll probably need some help burning that one).

Comment: TI-NSpire family of calculators don't use the TI-BASIC as the TI-84 or TI-83 or TI-89. What alternatives did you use for those tagged TI-Nspire?

Comment: @Rapptz I don't recall exactly, but I believe either nothing or [tag:calculator] where appropriate.